# Can I use the Nexus-S GPS as an external GPS for another device (via Bluetooth)?

Tags: gps, bluetooth, samsung-nexus-s

Is it possible to use the Nexus-S GPS as an external GPS for another device (via Bluetooth) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried these apps:

- [GPS 2 Bluetooth v.2](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cajax.gps2bt2)
- [Bluetooth GPS Output](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.meowsbox.btgps)
- [Tether GPS Lite](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.comptonsoft.tgps_lite)
- [GPS Tether](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gpstether)

Answer (score 2):

Great answer from Lie Ryan.

Just adding one more option : [blue NMEA](http://max.kellermann.name/projects/blue-nmea/)