# Connect Android GPS with Computer

Tags: 2.2-froyo, gps, samsung-galaxy-5, remote-access

Is this possible to connect my Android's GPS with my computer? I have a Samsung Galaxy Fit running Froyo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your computer has Bluetooth (most laptops do, and some wireless keyboards and mice connect through a bluetooth adaptor), then there are apps that will allow you to share your phone's GPS device to the PC as a bluetooth GPS adaptor.

See this previous question for some of them: [Can I use the Nexus-S GPS as an external GPS for another device (via Bluetooth)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/can-i-use-the-nexus-s-gps-as-an-external-gps-for-another-device-via-bluetooth)